# Does try/except block causes commit_on_success to fail

Tags: python, django, exception

```
@transection.commit_on_success
def recordIt(...)
   try:
       ....
       recordable = firstDataInsertionFunction(...)
       if recordable:
          myRec = SecondDataInsertion(.....)

    except:
       ....
```

As for **commit_on_success**, if my second data insertion fails, django must automatically rollback, so my first data insertion will be rolled back too...

But this is not working, and first inserted data is saved to db, while i could not see the result of second insertion on my database... Is try/except causes commit_on_success to fail? Because as documentation says:

> If the function returns successfully, then Django will commit all work done within the function at that point. If the function raises an exception, though, Django will roll back the transaction.

And try handles all exceptions. Is is the problem of my not working **commit_on_success**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't ever do `except:`. It's just bad, and catches too much, and hides bugs.

And yes, if you handle the exception, then `commit_on_success` cannot possibly know there was an error. If you need to run logic on exception, reraise it afterwards (just `raise`, with no argument). Or rollback yourself.